# Using hotcorners to move between spaces/desktops

Tags: macos, spaces

I would like to use hot corners to move between desktop/spaces. Right now, the only way to move between desktop with a mouse, is to go via Mission Control and clicking on the desired desktop. I want something faster without using keyboard shortcuts.
Is there any programs available or is there a code I should edit?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a magic mouse with gestures turned on you can two finger swipe left or right to scroll through the desktops.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [CornerClick](http://greg.vario.us/cornerclick/), which will allow you to add some default actions on hot corners.

And if you want to find some more tips and trucs about hot corners and your mouse, I can suggest you read [this article](http://ezinearticles.com/?Mac-Hot-Corners---Make-the-Most-of-Your-Mac-Mouse&id=1125435).